# Сохранение типа и дальнейшее приведение к нему (?)

Tags: c++, ооп, std, приведение-типов, any

Было необходимо реализовать класс-обертку для указателя на функцию (с любым числом любых параметров) для ее дальнейшего вызова. Так же было необходимо, чтобы объекты этого класса можно было помещать в контейнеры, поэтому пришлось избегать использования шаблонного класса, что очень упростило бы все (да и так уже есть std::function).

Вышло как-то так:

```
class COperation
{
public:
    template<typename ReturnType, typename ...Operands>
    COperation(ReturnType (*function)(Operands...)) {
        m_functionInterface = new Concreate<ReturnType, Operands...>(function);
    }
    ~COperation() {
        //delete m_functionInterface; // Почему-то падает
    }

public:
    template<typename ...Operands>
    void execute(Operands... args)
    {
        std::vector<std::any> argList;
        (argList.push_back(args), ...);
        m_functionInterface->execute(argList);
    }
    size_t operandCount() const
    {
        return  m_functionInterface->operandCount();
    }

private:
    struct Interface
    {
        virtual ~Interface() = default;

        virtual size_t operandCount() const = 0;
        virtual void execute(std::vector<std::any>) = 0;
    };

    template<typename R, typename ...Args>
    struct Concreate : Interface
    {
        explicit Concreate(R (*function)(Args...))
        {
            m_operandCount = sizeof...(Args);
            m_function = function;
        }

        size_t operandCount() const override
        {
            return m_operandCount;
        }

        void execute(std::vector<std::any> argList) override
        {
            if (argList.size() != sizeof...(Args)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Incorrect number of arguments.");
            }

            auto applyArgums = [argList](auto&&... args)
            {
                qsizetype n = 0;
                ((args = std::any_cast<typeof(args)>(argList.at(n++))), ...);
            };
            std::apply(applyArgums, m_operands);
            result = std::apply(m_function, m_operands);
            qDebug() << result;
        }

    private:
        R (*m_function)(Args...);
        std::tuple<Args...> m_operands;
        qsizetype m_operandCount;
        R result;
    };

private:
    Interface* m_functionInterface;
};
```

Функции для примера:

```
inline constexpr qreal addition(qreal left, qreal rigth)
{
    return left + rigth;
}

inline constexpr qreal unaryMinus(qreal operand)
{
    return -operand;
}
```

Использование:

```
COperation a(addition);
COperation um(unaryMinus);

a.execute(10., 20.); // 30
um.execute(10.);     // -10
```

Понятно, что много всего еще можно сделать, но я уже наткнулся на проблему.
Из примера видно, что приходится явно передавать параметры нужного типа, так как в противном случае ловим bad any_cast тут.

```
((args = std::any_cast<typeof(args)>(argList.at(n++))), ...);
```

Собственно, в этом и есть главная проблема, которую не удается мне решить. В "std::tuple<Args...> m_operands" хранятся аргументы функции "R(*m_function)(Args...);". Нужен механизм, позволяющий преобразовать входные в "execute" параметры к типам из "std::tuple<Args...> m_operands", если это возможно. То есть, например, int мы должны преобразовывать в double (и наоборот), так как это возможно, а не ловить ошибку, как сейчас. Можно ли это как-то реализовать в рамках std::auto? Либо, возможно, как-то переделать функцию "execute"? Из рабочих вариантов было использование std::variant, но мне бы не хотелось ограничиваться типами, которые мы сами указываем. Возможно, у вас будут идеи?)

Comment: `//delete m_functionInterface; // Почему-то падает` Лол. Используйте `std::unique_ptr` лучше. Для интереса можно почитать про [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Это понятно, отложил на потом этот момент и забыл удалить. Вопрос главный не в этом) За ссылку все равно спасибо.

Comment: В общем виде автоматически это никак не сделать. Все равно где-то надо будет вручную регистрировать все типы, и списки того, во что и из чего их можно преобразовать. По сравнению с `variant`, это позволяет не перечислять все типы в одном большом хедере, но с другой стороны надо будет руками перечислять список того, во что какой тип можно преобразовать.

Comment: Теоретически, нешаблонные конструкторы и операторы преобразования может и можно обнаруживать (конструкторы - чем-то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793557/2752075)), но это муторно, и не факт, что вообще получится.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще это нужно?

Comment: Пару раз возникали моменты, когда такая обертка была нужна. По началу казалось, что не очень сложно будет сделать, потом возникли разные трудности, решил, что того не стоит. А сейчас  уже на чистом интузиазме стало интересно доделать)

Comment: Обычно когда задают такие вопросы, потом оказывается, что проще хранить `std::function` - в отдельных списках, под каждые типы аргументов отдельно.

Comment: Не спорю, по-этому и не стал изобретать велосипед. Но для себя все же интересно было доделать.

Comment: Если ограничится архитектурами в которых [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) ограничены регистрами, то можно написать ассемблерные оберки для сохранения регистров при регистрации функции (запоминает аргументы) и для занесения сохраненных ранее аргументов в регистры и вызова функции (по ее запомненному адресу). Наверное нужно будет ввести такое ограничение -- пользователь вызывает в зависимости от типа (целое (тут в т.ч. любой указатель) или real) разные обертки. Понятно, еще одно ограничение это возврат структуры. Сходу не могу представить простую реализацию

Comment: Ну, а вообще... Такие задачи я бы программировал на другом языке, чем-нибудь вроде лиспа

Comment: Ну, писал на том языке, на котором изначально мне и было нужно) А насчет сложных реализаций, конечно, такой цели нет. Просто вдруг было бы какое-то элегантное и простое решение (или хотя бы, которое я бы смог воссоздать), которое я сам не смог придумать. Раз такого нет, это тоже ответ, который я хотел узнать. Спасибо.